# Laravel request validation doesn't show error messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

After I used group middleware, I am not able to access error messages. Error bags returns empty.

**There was no problem before.**

I have researched, some users have solved the problem by changing **http/kernel.php**

*\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,* **$middlewareGroups** to **$middleware**.

However, It doesn't work for me.

Also **$validated = $request->validated();** function doesnt returns validation error. In my CreditcardRequest Class I have attributes, messages, rules functions. If validation fails these messages needs to be shown. 
previously When validated();  method was running on the controller, it was showing the messages if the form is empty. I have 20 pages all of them working, before middleware grouping.

**Creditcard Blade**

```
<div class="messages">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="row  mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h3 class="alert-heading font-size-h4 font-w400">Error!</h3>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <p class="mb-0">{{ $error }}</p>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

**CreditcardRequest**

```
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'cc_name' => 'CC Owner',
        ..
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => 'Required: :attribute',
        ...
    ];
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'cc_name' => 'required|max:128',
    ];
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function doPaySection(CreditcardRequest $request)
  {

      $validated = $request->validated();
      $cc = TRUE;
      if ($cc):
          return redirect('/pay_success')->with('success', 'success');
      else:
          return redirect('/pay_error')->with('error', 'error');
      endif;
  }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['client.role:guest']], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'HomepageController@showLogin')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'HomepageController@doLogin');
    Route::post('/register', 'HomepageController@doRegister');
    Route::get('/register', 'HomepageController@showRegister')->name('register');
});
```

**login.blade**

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="row  mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="alert-heading font-size-h4 font-w400">Hata!</h3>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <p class="mb-0">{{ $error }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Controller**

```
public function doLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (auth()->guard('client')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the auth that comes with Laravel? The code you have at the minute won't add an "error" to the `error bag`.

Comment: its not only auth error, I have a lot of forms and I am checking all of them with $request->validated(); method. It should be return an error when inputs are empty. I added my another controller for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have at the minute won't add a message to the `$errors` `MessageBag`, it will simply add a value to the session called error.

If you want to add an error to the message bag you could simply throw a `ValidationException` which redirect `back` with that message:

```
public function doLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (auth()->guard('client')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'error' => 'The error message',
    ]);
}
```

Don't forget to import `ValidationException` with:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

Comment: sir thank you. it worked for login page. but I am still not able to get validation errors. before creating middleware I can show error messages with request->validated(); but now errors returns empty. I edited question btw.

Comment: @tyasird The `validated()` method isn't for displaying errors, it's to get the properties from the request that you have validated (included in your Form Request class). When you type hint a Form Request class as an attribute of a controller method the validation will happen automatically, if the validation fails then it won't run a single line in your controller method and will simply redirect back to the previous page with the errors. What error(s) are you expecting to see??

Comment: In my RequestClass I have attributes, messages, rules functions. If validation fails this messages needs to be shown. 
previously When validated();  method was running on controller, it was showing the messages  if the form is empty. I have 20 pages all of them working, before middleware grouping

Comment: @tyasird **Specifically** what error message are you expecting to see?

Comment: I expect to see form input required error. As you can see on my CreditcardRequest class, form input cc_name shouldnt be empty.  in the CreditcardRequest class there are error messages and required input names that I expect to validation. The error should returned when input was empty, but now it does not returns any error. validation works there is no problem but I cant see validation errors on blade.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try using this header in your request. Especially if you are hitting from postman.

```
Accept:application/json
```

Before using this, i was getting csrf token in case of invalid requests.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your will be able to get in `session('error')`from below

```
return redirect()->back()->with('errors', 'error');
```

So your code would be like

```
@if (session('errors'))
    <div class="row  mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="alert-heading font-size-h4 font-w400">Hata!</h3>
                @foreach (session('errors') as $error)
                    <p class="mb-0">{{ $error }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```